# Amazon AWS PHP SDK - Cluster fails to launch -The given SSH key name was invalid

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, emr

I am trying to create a PHP page to launch cluster and add jobs to the jobflow.

```
$response = $emr->run_job_flow($nameOfRun, array(
        'Ec2KeyName' => 'hadoop',
        'HadoopVersion' => '0.20',
        'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps' => $clusterAlive,
        'InstanceGroups' => array(
                array( // Group #1
                        'InstanceCount' => $numOfMaster,
                        'InstanceRole' => 'MASTER',
                        'InstanceType' => $masterInstanceType,
                        'Market' => 'ON_DEMAND',
                        'Name' => 'Master',
                ),
                array( // Group #2
                        'InstanceCount' => $numOfSlaves,
                        'InstanceRole' => 'CORE',
                        'InstanceType' => $slaveInstanceType,
                        'Market' => 'ON_DEMAND',
                        'Name' => 'Slaves',
                )
        ),
        'Placement' => array(
                'AvailabilityZone' => 'us-east-1d'
        )
));
```

The cluster is launched and I can see the job flow ID. But it starts to shut down immediately after launch. When I do a `elastic-mapreduce --list`, for that cluster the state is Failed.

Any known issues or anywhere I am doing wrong? Is AvailabilityZone may be causing the issue?

I checked from the AWS Console, it is giving this error - `The given SSH key name was invalid`
I checked, the access key and secret key I provided in config.inc.php are correct and working.

Regards,
Kartikeya Sinha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there are four different gotchas that might cause the error, as outlined in this [AWS thread:](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=208470)

1. Specifying the exact keypair name from the console.
2. Specifying a keypair that exists in a different region than your the region of your endpoint.
3. Using a keypair for a different AWS service, instead of one for EC2.
4. Using a renamed keypair pem file, when it should match the keypair in the console (really a special case of 1).

If all that looks right, try deleting the keypair and making a new one.

---

Based on a reading of the [PHP SDK](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonEMR/run_job_flow) docs, I think the problem is that you're specifying `EC2KeyName` at all (your comments suggest you don't want to tie a particular pem file to the EC2 instances; you rather just want access with a secret key and access key).

> Ec2KeyName - string - Optional - Specifies the name of the Amazon EC2 key pair that can be used to ssh to the master node as the user called “hadoop.” [Constraints: The value must be between 0 and 256 characters, and must match the following regular expression pattern:
>
> [\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF\r\n\t]*]

This parameter refers to the pem keypair files you can associate with EC2 instances. Your comments suggest you're speaking specifically about AccessKeys and SecretAccessKeys, which are different concepts. The pem files give you `ssh` access to EC2 instances. The latter authorize you against the AWS API.

You should be able to kill that optional parameter and have the job work, although you won't be able to `ssh` into its affiliated EC2 instances without a pem file.

Comment: About the 3rd point: How to know a keypair is for EC2 or not? In AWS console there is no such option to view this.

Comment: @akki If it's listed here, it is (note this is the URL for the us-east-1 region): https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-1#s=KeyPairs

Comment: I have checked, first 3 points are okay.
1. Keypair is exact
2. It is from the same region - us-east-1
3. This keypair is listed for EC2 service.
About 4th point, AWS SDK for PHP only needs Access Key and Secret key to work, no pem files I guess. Right?

Comment: @akki Would try creating a new one. If that doesn't work, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: thanks for your help. Will try creating a new one and will update for the same

Comment: Repeating if you have missed:  About 4th point, AWS SDK for PHP only needs Access Key and Secret key to work, no pem files I guess. Right?

Comment: @akki I think I figured out the issue. Edited my answer with some references to the AWS SDK.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christopher. It helped. Actually, the keypair name I supplied here was not same as the access key/secret key pair name.

Answer (score 0):

Where I was wrong: (This solved my case)
The name of the keypair of which access key and secret key are specified in the config.ini.php file of AWS SDK and the EC2KeyName to be supplied while launching a cluster should be the same.